# Java: Something is getting lost when += is applied

Tags: java, floating-point

This is my code, but its output does make any sense.

```
long currentTime;
long stateStartTime;
int delta;
float speed;

// I do something

System.out.println();
System.out.println(currentTime);
System.out.println(stateStartTime);
System.out.println(delta);
System.out.println(speed);
System.out.println(delta * speed);
System.out.println(currentTime - (stateStartTime + (delta * speed)));
stateStartTime += delta * speed;
System.out.println(currentTime - stateStartTime);
```

Output:

```
1350065634345877
1350065121656832
1
5.0E8
5.0E8
0.0
-24181867
```

I was expecting the last two rows to be:

```
12689045
12689045
```

But surprisingly I got the above result. Why?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing something... but we can't see what :)

Comment: Your Java code has _eight_ print statements, but the output only has _seven_ lines.  My guess here is overflow/rounding error of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't drop precision and expect the computer to re-create it.

```
long currentTime = 1350065634345877L;
long stateStartTime = 1350065121656832L;
long delta = 1L;
double speed = 5.0E8;
```

And your last two lines (with no other changes) output

```
1.2689045E7
12689045
```

To make the penultimate line match the final line, you could use a `BigDecimal` like

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(currentTime - (stateStartTime + (delta * speed)))
        .toPlainString());
```

Comment: I thought that long + float will cast the float to double first, I guess it's sending the long to float.